# How to spy on npm library function (Node.js)?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, jasmine

I'm using [express-prom-bundle](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-prom-bundle) to provide a prometheus statistics endpoint, this library creates a middleware that is applied to an Express app:

```
import promBundle from 'express-prom-bundle';
...
app.use(promBundle({
   includeMethod: process.env.PROMETHEUS_INCLUDE_METHOD === 'true' ? true : false,
   includePath: process.env.PROMETHEUS_INCLUDE_PATH === 'true' ? true : false,
   includeStatusCode: process.env.PROMETHEUS_INCLUDE_STATUS_CODE === 'true' ? true : false,
}));
```

This is what I'm currently trying to do:

```
import * as promBundle from 'express-prom-bundle';
...

spyOn(promBundle, 'default');
spyOnProperty(promBundle, 'default').and.returnValue({});

expect(promBundle).toHaveBeenCalled();
```

but I'm receiving the following error:
`Error: <spyOn> : default is not declared writable or has no setter Usage: spyOn(<object>, <methodName>)`

How it could be mocked and tested by Jasmine?
Coverage shows that lines where `process.env` variables are checking need to be tested.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why bother testing whether or not a third-party library and `process.env` work? Also, `process.env.FOO === 'true' ? true : false` could be shortened to just `process.env.FOO === 'true'`.